# $x \rightarrow a \cdot x$ is surjective in a finite ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

In Dummit and Foote, 3rd edition, p.228, corollary 3

> Any finite integral domain is a field.

In the proof:

> Let $R$ be a finite integral domain and let $a$ be a nonzero element of $R$. By the cancellation law the map $x \rightarrow ax$ is an injective function. Since $R$ is finite this map is also surjective.

Could someone detail why is this map surjective in that case ? I need to use $a^{-1}$ for this, but since you need to prove its existence...

Comment: It has nothing to do with rings. If you have a map $f:A\rightarrow B$ that is injective, and $A$ and $B$ are finite sets of same cardinality, then $f$ is a surjection necessarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call $f$ your map. If I were mean, I'd use Dedekind's definition:

> By injectivity, the image of $f$ is a subset of $R$ which is in bijection with $R$. Since $R$ is not infinite, the only such subset is $R$ itself.

However, the more colloquial way to state it is that $R$ has $n$ elements, and by injectivity the image of $f$ is a subset of $R$ with at least $n$ elements. Therefore it is $R$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the function is defined for all elements of R and is injective and R is finite it must be surjective.